# multiple save from result php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**this form will store the same data in the amount of the result**

```
 <form method="post" action="multi_insert.php">

  <input type="text" name="nis" placeholder="NIS"/>
  <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Nama"/>
    <input type="number" name="result" >

  <br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
 </form>
```

"and this is source code for save named `multi_insert.php`"

```
include "koneksi.php";

for($i=0;$i<$_POST['result'];$i++){
 $nis = $_POST['nis'.$i];
 $nama= $_POST['nama'.$i];
 $query = "insert into SISWA(NIS,NAMA)values('$nis','$nama')";
 $mysqli->query($query);
}
$mysqli->close();
```

and this connectiondb or koneksi.php

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "SEKOLAH";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
exit;
```

Comment: What is the question actually?

Comment: i can't  save to database
what wrong with my code

Comment: Is the connection to the database successful? What is the error you get??

Comment: connection is succesful and no error for show

Comment: Use name="nama[]" instead of name="nama" only.

Comment: Constructing SQL this way is dangerous and open to SQL injection attacks. you should use replaceable parameters in prepared statements in your sql code and never use string interpolation or concatenation to build sql queries with user supplied data. Imagine I filled out your form and supplied "');DROP DATABASE; --" as the input to the NIS field.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['nis'.$i]` is not exist..

you should use only `$_POST['nis']`..

i do correction for your code:

```
include "koneksi.php";

for($i=0;$i<$_POST['result'];$i++){
 $nis = $_POST['nis'];
 $nama= $_POST['nama'];
 $query = "insert into SISWA(NIS,NAMA)values('$nis','$nama')";
 $mysqli->query($query);
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form method="post" action="multi_insert.php">

  <input type="text" name="nis" placeholder="NIS"/>
  <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Nama"/>
    <input type="number" name="result" >

  <br/>

  <button type="submit" >submit</button>
 </form>
```

```
if($_POST['nis'] && $_POST['nama']) {
    $nis = $_POST['nis'];
    $nama= $_POST['nama'];
    $query = "insert into SISWA(NIS,NAMA)values('$nis','$nama')";
    $mysqli->query($query);
}
$mysqli->close();
```

if you need save multiple input value with same name you should use

```html
<input name="nama[]" />
<input name="nama[]" />
<input name="nama[]" />
```

instead of

```html
<input name="nama" />
```

and the value $_POST['nama'] will be an array

```
if($_POST['nama']) {
    foreach($_POST['nama'] as $i => $v) {
        $query = "insert into SISWA(NAMA)values('$v')";
        $mysqli->query($query);
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: i can save,, but the record is array

Comment: @kagami you need foreach $_POST['nama'] to access the value if you use name=nama[] in the front

Comment: use for
for($i=0;$i<$_POST['result'];$i++){
 $nis = $_POST['nis'];
 $nama= $_POST['nama'];
 $query = "insert into SISWA(NIS,NAMA)values('$nis','$nama')";
 $mysqli->query($query);
}

Comment: I have changed to nama[]
and in the database the record is array

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<input type="text" name="nama[]" />`, `$_POST['nama']` is not an input value but an array.To get the value you should rather say

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['nama']);$i++){
   $nama= $_POST['nama'][$i];
 }
```

That way u can the use `$nama` or whatever variable as a paramaeter in your PREPARED STATEMENT.
Your method of using of using $_POST['nama'.$i] will work if you create manually or through javascript your inputs to be

```
<input type="text" name="name1"/>
<input type="text" name="name2"/> et.c
```